# H2 incrementally update counts from another table?

Tags: sql, database, merge, h2

With the H2 database, suppose there is a SUMS table that has a key and several count fields and there is an UPDATES table which has the same key and count fields. The keys in the UPDATES table may or may not exist in the SUMS table.

What is the most efficient way to add all the counts for each key from the UPDATES table to the SUM table, or insert a row with those counts if the SUMS table does not yet have it?

Of course I could always process the result set of a select on the UPDATES table and then one-by-one update or insert into the SUMS table, but this feels like there should be a more efficient way to do it.

If it is not possible in H2 but possible in some other Java-embeddable solution I would be interested in this too, because this processing is just an intermediate step for processing a larger number of these counts (a couple of dozen million keys and a couple of billion rows for updating them).

Comment: You can try the `merge` statement:  http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge.

Comment: I am probably missing something here, but how can I add the value from the UPDATES table into the value in the SUMS table with MERGE?